# How to read E-value annotation on NCBI BLAST?

Tags: sequence-alignment, statistics, blast, phylogenetics

I am seeking clarification on how to read the  `E` value annotation on NCBI's BLAST results.

What I understand so far:

> E -values are the expected value of the number of random querys of the same length as the input that would result in a even or better S-score on the same sized database. Since E-values are estimates, not probabilities , they can be lower than 0.

However, if NCBI BLAST retuns an e-value of say: "4e -19" do they mean:

- $ {4 \cdot 10^{-19}} $ (this would not result in negative values )
- or do they mean 4 E-19 as in : "*four queries score better in S with a -19 difference*"

Comment: It's a number in regular scientific format, so it's the former. `4e-19` = `4 * 10^-19`

Comment: thanks for the reassurance! .. man, sometimes i stumble upon one source that uses a weird notation and i start to get quite confused.. The source of my confusion was Victor Flores comment on  https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_E-value_exactly_means_and_what_is_it_1e-63_representing

Comment: After rereading i could have seen earlier that he is apparently wrong.

Comment: He never says anything that resembles your second interpretation. How did you end up with that interpretation?

Comment: You are totally right, i confused "beyond" with "below" (not a native english speaker) . This should never have resulted in such a stupid confusion,  unfortunately the feedback at university is a little bit sparse due to the pandemic circumstances , so you had to bare with my undergrad incertitude. I honestly thank you for clearing it out nonetheless. On the upside i learned my lesson, took a step back and studied Altschuls formulation.

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad I could help. A lot of the long-winded description of these terms can make one confused but as you gain some practical experience, you'd understand these better.